# Restart Services and Set to Automatic from Manual after the Last Successful Patch is Installed

Tags: windows, powershell

writing a PowerShell script to detect a given number of planned patches have been installed - then restart an application's services.  For example four patches are going to be installed - and you don't know if the four patches all require reboot.  The objective is to restart application services and reset them from Manual to Automatic after the forth patch is installed - whether the server has been rebooted after the last 4th patch or not.

You then have the PowerShell script run via Task Scheduler every time "when the computer starts up" to it will look for the counter to be at 4.  This would be easy if every time a patch was installed a reboot would launch the script. The if the counter shows the forth patch installed successfully - do the Start-Service for the application and Set-Service -StartupType  back to  Automatic.

How would you deal with the logic condition that says if the last patch does not require a reboot -- get the counter = 4 (the last successful patch install) allowing you to restart the  services?

```
$loopCount = 0
do{
##HERE YOU SET THE DATE TO THE BEGINING OF THE DAY THE PATCHES WILL BE INSTALLED
$count =  Get-HotFix | ? installedon -gt "4/13/2022 00:00:00" | Group installedon –NoElement |
    ForEach-Object Count
    

    $loopCount++
##HERE YOU SET THE COUNT BASED ON HOW MANY KB##### PATCHES WILL BE INSTALLED USING QA COUNT (example below is 4)
    if($count -eq 4){

$s = Get-Service WatchDog
Start-Service -InputObject $s | Set-Service -Name WatchDog -StartupType Automatic
        $counted = $true
    }

} until ($counted -eq $true)
```

Comment: How are you testing if the update requires a reboot?

Comment: we have a patch to prod - testing process.  Starting with Dev, then QA servers.  When it's at Prod - we know the patches are not troubling to the application.  Our current patching on Prod is requiring us to manually shutdown the application services - set them to manual - and after the patch team finishes patching - we are notified to manually bring up the application.  We want to automate the shutdown of the app before patching and restart the application services after all the patching has been done - maybe several reboots occur - we need the application to start after the last patch.

Comment: we cannot test if the patches require rebooting is the issue.  The patch team applies the patches across the organization - we determined we need to shut the application services and set the services to manual - to bring up the application smoothly when patching is done.  This is what we need to automate.

Comment: you asked `How would you deal with the logic condition that says if the last patch does not require a reboot?` but we cannot make a logic statement to test this flag this if a flag does not exist. You have to create a flag or test to track if reboot are required.